# Tomcat Comet event not called - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: tomcat, comet, nio

I am trying to implement a Comet process.

Tomcat 6.0.36

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

Java 7u11 (32 bit)

I have implemented CometProcessor.  I am using the NIO connector.
When I try the servlet I get: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL.
The other topics I have found on this matter advise people to make sure they are using the NIO connector. I have.  I have also seen recommendations to make sure the catalina.jar was not packaged with the web app. I have checked that also.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Code snippet:

```
public class ConsolidatedActionCenterPush extends HttpServlet  implements CometProcessor,CAC{

  private static MessageSender messageSender = null;
  private static final Integer TIMEOUT = 600 * 1000;

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    messageSender.stop();
    messageSender = null;
  }

  @Override
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    messageSender = new MessageSender();
    messageSender.start();

  }


  @Override
  public void event(final CometEvent event) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = event.getHttpServletRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = event.getHttpServletResponse();

 ........

}
```

From catalina log:

```
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in     production environments was not found on the java.library.path:     /usr/jre732/lib/i386/server:/usr/jre732/lib/i386:/usr/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:20 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:20 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 540 ms
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory servlet
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:10794
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/18  config=null
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3127 ms
```

From catalina.out:

```
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:10794
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/18  config=null
Jan 22, 2013 11:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3127 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I was using the invoker servlet because we have a lot of un-mapped servlets. Removing the invoker servlet fixed the comet process.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer as i am also facing the exact same problem with comet

Comment: @kunal I'm sorry but Comet is no longer supported in Tomcat. Web sockets are the current way to do this type of thing.

Comment: @kunal - https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html#Comet_support_removed

Comment: But what if i use older version of tomcat ?

Comment: Sorry friend, this was far too long ago to remember further details. For that matter, I cannot imagine a scenario where implementing a comet connection at this point in the game would be advisable. Tomcat 8 is the latest version that supports comet connections, and it will be abandoned next month: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html